# Ancestor queries with Objectify4

Tags: java, objectify

I'm trying to do this:

```
Resource resource = (Resource) ofy().load().ancestor(new Key<Resource>(Resource.class, key)).first().getValue();
```

This pattern works before with v3 but with v4 it won't because of

```
The constructor Key<Resource>(Class<? extends T>, String) is not visible
```

How to do ancestor queries with Objectify4>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a Key with `Key.create()`.